# Instagram authentication scope param using coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, instagram

I have an Instagram application written in Coldfusion 8 that basically pulls in media by tags and then allows people to Like / vote on the photos which is all done via the Instagram API. The Liking part is causing me no end of grief though, as I can get the Authentication and Access_Token without a drama, however the Access_Token doesn't appear to have permission to Like by default. There is an optional param for the Authenticate call "scope" which allows you to pass the permissions allowed for the Access_Token but i cannot work out how to pass this via ColdFusion CFHTTP as a POST.

Here is the preparation for the data to be sent over CFHTTP looping over all params as type="FormField". No matter how I try and present the scope options, either JSON format, string with spaces, string with "+" delimiters it seems to have no effect and the Like operation continues to fail due to permission errors.

```
<cfscript>
    var LOCAL = {};
    LOCAL['config'] = {};
    LOCAL['returnStruct'] = {};

    // prep packet required by the main call method
    // the following values are required for EVERY call
    LOCAL['config']['method'] = 'POST';
    LOCAL['config']['format'] = ARGUMENTS['outputType'];
    LOCAL['config']['url'] = VARIABLES.authURL;

    // variables required by this method
    LOCAL['config']['params'] = {};
    LOCAL['config']['params']['client_secret'] = ARGUMENTS.client_secret;
    LOCAL['config']['params']['grant_type'] = 'authorization_code';
    LOCAL['config']['params']['redirect_uri'] = ARGUMENTS.redirect_uri;
    LOCAL['config']['params']['code'] = ARGUMENTS.code;
    LOCAL['config']['params']['scope'] = 'likes comments relationships';

</cfscript>
```

Comment: Have you tried appending the scope to the URL instead of part of the post? You should still be able to send post data with a query string. `LOCAL['config']['url'] = VARIABLES.authURL & '?scope=likes+comments+relationships'`

Comment: Hi Travis thanks for the response. After mucking around with this for another 5-6hrs today i finally found out what the problem was. Instagram documentation misleading! The scope doesn't appear to work when passed during the 3rd phase of the Authentication no matter how many ways i try and pass it, so I went back and tacked the scope=likes+comments+relationships onto the https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize initial step and it worked! So i ended up wasting around 10hrs due to misleading documentation from Instagram on where to place the scope argument.

Comment: That's great I'm glad you were able to solve the problem.  I would try to file a bug report or whatever process instagram has to fix documentation issues.  I'd also write that up as an official answer on Stack Overflow for future users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else is running into the same issues with "scope" not being correctly applied to the return Access_Token it turns out the problem was Instagram Documentation being vague about where this argument should be used. I had tried it every way possible as a POST operation as it suggested during the server-side Authentication, however it appears to only work if sent as GET params and after some playing around I decided to tack the "scope" param onto the 2nd stage of the authentication which is where the Code is requested and that worked! See below
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code&scope=likes+basic

This will present the user with an confirmation message from Instagram to allow the application to perform Likes on behalf of the user and everything else works like a charm after this.